# Eclipse EGit Not Opening File Comparison

Tags: eclipse, egit

I am using Eclipse (Photon 4.8.0) for a Git project. Before committing, I have been double clicking the files which appear in the `unstaged changes` section of the `Git Staging View` to remind myself of what I have changed before writing the commit message (I'm still new to Git so occasionally I will do several things before remembering that I have to commit my changes). However, double clicking on the file today merely opens the file, rather than opening the `comparison view`. I can still open the `comparison view` by right clicking the file and selecting `Compare with Index` but this takes more time and is frustrating.

As far as I know, I haven't changed any settings (not intentionally anyway). Can someone explain to me how to get back the behaviour I was seeing before please?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make sure, in the *Git Staging* view toolbar the [image: Compare Mode] ***Compare Mode*** button is pressed.

See also [EGit User Guide of the History view with the same icon](https://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide#Compare_Mode).

Comment: Brilliant, thank you. I must have clicked it by accident when changing repos