# Eclipse-Git: Open version from another Branch, Tag, or Reference using egit

Tags: java, eclipse, git, compare, egit

When reviewing code, I often would like to open another version of the current file from another branch in a new editor window. Example: When reviewing changes in `Example.java` from `feature-branch-1234`, I want to open the `Example.java` from `develop` or `master`.

I know I can right click on the file contents, *Compare With* -> *Branch, Tag, or Reference*. But that would open the Compare view which contains both versions, and I do want to have a 'full sized view' on the original version and I want to scroll both versions independently.

Is there an easy way to open another version of the current file in a new Eclipse editor window?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Eclipse EGit Not Opening File Comparison](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53885339/eclipse-egit-not-opening-file-comparison)

Comment: In your case, you have to uncheck the _Compare Mode_ button which exists in both, the _History_ view and the _Git Staging_ view: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53886334/6505250

Comment: @howlger I don't see how the referenced answer can be of any help... I know that feature, but that's something completely different. The History / Staging views are based on *commits*, not on *trees*. If I compare a file from `feature-branch-1234` with `develop`, there may be 100 changing commits to that file. I would have to search for the last commit in the source branch (`develop`). And then, yes, I can toggle the button if I just don't want to right click and select *Open* instead of *Compare*.

Comment: The _History_ view can follow the editor and when you have entered `develop` in the _Find Toolbar_ you just have to double-click the commit in bold (make sure the _Find Toolbar_, _Show All Branches and Tags_ and _Link with Editor and Selection_ are enabled).

Comment: @howlger My *History* view is linked with the Editor / Selection. But in the *Find* field, I can not search for branches, it only searches commit messages. I just tried it, and the commit in bold is from 2018, while the last commit to the file in `develop` was in July. I also selected *Show all Branches and Tags*.

Comment: But we're close!

Comment: For me the _Find Toolbar_ also finds branch and tag names. I have EGit 5.4. Which version do you have?

Comment: @howlger I also have EGit 5.4, and all columns are shown in that view. *Find* doesn't find the last commit to the currently selected file in the branch name when searching for the branch name. It finds commits with messages like "Merging branch xyz into develop".
So we *almost* got there. The referenced question however is not a duplicate, it addresses the question why *Open* (instead of *Compare*) is the default action for doubleclick.